# C# Poker Game: No argument given that responds to required formal parameter

Tags: c#, class

I'm making a poker game using C# that randomly generates a hand to a player, then checks to see if there are any combinations and determines a winner.

In my player class, that generates a player's hand, I am getting a an error saying "No argument given that responds to required formal parameter 's' of Card.Card(Card.Suit, Card.Number)" when I hover over 'Player' and have so far been unable to fix the issue, despite having researched it.

Here is the code:

```
class Player : Card
{
    Deck PlayerDeck = new Deck();
    public List<Card> hand = new List<Card>();

    public void GenerateHand()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Card c = PlayerDeck.RandomCard();
            hand.Add(c);
            PlayerDeck.deck.Remove(c);
        }
    }
```

And the Card class if needed:

```
class Card
{
    public enum Combination
    {
        None, Flush, StraightFlush, Poker,
        ThreeKind, FullHouse, TwoPairs, Pair
    }

    public enum Suit
    {
        Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds
    }

    public enum Number : int
    {
        Ace = 1, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven,
        Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King
    }

    public Suit suit;
    public Number number;
    public Card(Suit s, Number n)
    {
        suit = s;
        number = n;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `: Card` from the class definition of Player. A Player is not logically a Card, so that inheritance doesn't make sense.

In order to create an instance of a class which inherits from another class, a constructor from the base class must first be called. In this case, the only constructor for Card takes two arguments. But you haven't defined any constructors for Player which call that constructor for Card. In such a case, the compiler instead looks for a default (parameterless) constructor for Card, which doesn't exist, hence the error.